# How do I import mail from one Gmail account to another Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, authentication, pop3

If you google that question as is, you get a plethora of links and "how to's" on how to do it.

[This](http://lifehacker.com/352401/migrate-all-your-old-gmail-to-a-new-gmail-address) and [this](http://lifehacker.com/5521065/how-to-migrate-email-from-one-gmail-account-to-another) or [this](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Move-Mail-From-One-Gmail-Account-To-Another-Using-Only-Gmail.htm), are practically useless. They are badly written, some steps are "missing" (like how do you go from Forwarding and POP/IMAP to so called "Pop Download"), and I think they are out of date as the interfaces and options in Gmail settings look different (as of Nov 2015).

It is obvious the methods explained are about "opening up" Gmail accounts to POP3 connections and treating the other Gmail account as an external POP3 account.

But it does not work for me.

Every time I give authentication to the POP3 settings of the "other" Gmail account, I get authentication denied errors. I've checked the Gmail passwords and access to both accounts on a separate browser and it's all OK.

I am trying to do this in latest Chrome, Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those steps are correct for example if you go to your settings and go to the Forwarding and POP/IMAP *tab* you will see three sections: Forwarding, POP Download, and IMAP Access.  With this said the steps straight from Google are as follows:

On the second account (the one mail is to be pulled FROM):

1. Click on the **Gear** icon in upper right corner.
2. Click on **Settings**.
3. Click on the **Forwarding and POP/IMAP** *tab*.
4. In the ***POP Download*** *section* next to step **1** select the **Enable POP for all mail** radio button.
5. Again in the ***POP Download*** *section* next to step **2** choose if you want keep, delete, or archive the messages after they are accessed.
6. Click on **Save Changes** on the bottom of the page.

On your main account (the one you want the mail to end up in):

1. Click on the **Gear** icon in upper right corner.
2. Click on **Settings**.
3. Click on the **Accounts and Import** *tab*.
4. In the ***Check mail from other accounts (using POP3)*** *section* click on **Add a POP3 mail account you own**.
5. Enter the *full email address* of your other Gmail account.
6. Enter your *password*. Note that 2-step verification will also require a new app password. *(See Below)*
7. Adjust the remaining options to your preferences.
   Google recommends that you:

   - *Leave unchecked* - Leave a copy of retrieved messages on the server.

     - this setting is controlled from the settings on the other account.
   - *Leave unchecked* - Archive incoming messages.

     - If you check this your messages will not appear in your inbox .
   - *Leave checked* - Always use a secure connection (SSL).

If you have 2-Step verification turned on you may need to generate an *App Password*:

On the second account (the one mail is to be pulled FROM):

1. Go to the [Apps Passwords Page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)
2. **Sign in** with the account you are *importing* **From**
3. At the bottom, click **Select app** and choose **Mail**.
4. Click **Select device** and choose the device you’re using (most likely **Windows Computer**)
5. Select **Generate**.
6. Enter the generated **App password** when you are setting up the Import on the main account.

You should only need to do this once and after that it should be available

Comment: Ok. Sorry but that is what the other links asked me to do as well. Every time I get this ... Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
Server returned error: "[AUTH] Application-specific password required: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833" And I am using the right password. So no, something else is happening here.

Comment: If I un-tick the "Always use a secure connection (SSL)...", I now get this ... There was a problem communicating with pop.gmail.com
Server returned error: "Connection closed by remote host: The other server terminated our connection. Please contact your other email provider for more information."

Comment: Same thing again with SMTP ...There was a problem communicating with smtp.gmail.com
Server returned error: "Connection closed by remote host: The other server terminated our connection. Please contact your other email provider for more information."

Comment: This is because of the 2-Step verification process. You need to setup a new app password. I will edit my answer with the steps for this.

Comment: Does not work (perhaps: anymore). I'm still stuck at the `Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password. Server returned error: "[AUTH] Username and password not accepted."` error.

Comment: To add: The only thing that worked for me is to have one Gmail account forward the emails to the other.